# Запятая при "после того как"

Tags: пунктуация

*После того как в конфликт вмешались родители, травля прекратилась.*

Нужна ли запятая перед словом "как" и почему?

Answer (score 3):

***После того как в конфликт вмешались родители***, травля прекратилась.

Сравнить: ***И только*** после того,  **как в конфликт вмешались родители,** травля прекратилась.

Это тема  **расчленения сложных подчинительных союзов**, в данном случае это союз ПОСЛЕ ТОГО КАК.

Союз чаще всего  **не расчленяется**, если придаточное находится **в начале** предложения.

В этом случае для расчленения обычно требуются **дополнительные условия** (например, наличие частицы перед союзом).

Ударение при расчленении союза  падает на его местоименную часть, что способствует **смысловому выделению придаточного**.

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138#pp138

Answer (score 2):

*Запятая не нужна.* Придаточное со всем этим оборотом обособляется, при этом запятая действительно может быть после *"как"* и не нужна тогда перед *"после".* Но поскольку у Вас предложение начинается с этого оборота, то запятая возможна *только при интонационном выделении слова **того**.*

Answer (score 1):

Запятая может быть поставлена в случае постановки логического ударения на слове **того**.  Хочу отметить, что в этом случае слово имеет связь с предыдущим предложением. В целом обособление не требуется.